# What does "2 skill ranks at each level" mean for the the Sage familiar archetype's Sage's Knowledge ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, skills, familiars, character-advancement

The Sage familiar archetype has the Sage’s Knowledge (Ex) ability:

> A sage stores information on every topic and is happy to lecture its
> master on the finer points. A sage can attempt all Knowledge checks
> untrained and receives a bonus on all Knowledge checks equal to 1/2
> its level. Additionally, a sage gains 2 skill ranks at each level.

Does "2 skill ranks at each level" mean 2 skill ranks to add to a singular skill, all skills, to a class skill, all class skills, a X-class skill, or all x-class skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Sage familiar gains two additional skill points per level

A [Sage familiar archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/familiar-archetypes/sage-familiar-archetype/) replaces the ability to share the master's skill ranks, which replaces the following ability granted to [familiars](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/):

> Skills: For each skill in which either the master or the familiar has ranks, use either the normal skill ranks for an animal of that type or the master’s skill ranks, whichever is better. In either case, the familiar uses its own ability modifiers. Regardless of a familiar’s total skill modifiers, some skills may remain beyond the familiar’s ability to use. Familiars treat Acrobatics, Climb, Fly, Perception, Stealth, and Swim as class skills.

Also, note that a normal familiar do not gain any skill ranks to improve their skills, as noted by the following line:

> use either the **normal skill ranks** for an animal of that type

This means that a normal [Fox familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/canines/fox/) would have the following skills:

> Skills Acrobatics +2 (+10 when jumping), Perception +8, Stealth +10, Survival +1 (+5 scent tracking); Racial Modifiers +4 Acrobatics when jumping, +4 Survival when tracking by scent

If we break down the skills to figure out the skill ranks invested on each skill, we have the following:

- Acrobatics: 0 (+2 from dex, this is only listed because of the jumping bonus)
- Perception: 1 (+3 class-skill, +3 skill-focus, +1 wis)
- Stealth: 0 (+2 dex, +8 small-sized)
- Survival: 0 (+1 wis, +4 scent)

That matches the description for skill ranks gained by [animals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Animal) (1 per HD).

A [Sage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/familiar-archetypes/sage-familiar-archetype/) fox familiar, instead of having a single rank in Perception, would **gain 3 skill ranks per level of the master** to distribute among her skills, and no longer would be able to use her master skill ranks as her own.

Comment: Just for the record, [Mark Seifer](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2thu8?Sage-Familiar-archetype-and-skill-points#2) says that it would get its normal ranks per HD + the Sage ranks.

Comment: Makes sense, it says you gain. That makes it 3 skill ranks per level for most familiars.