# Do wizard familiars get skill points to distribute? REF#Sage’s Knowledge (Ex)

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Nowhere in the wizard class page does it say that a familiar gets its 1 skillPoint/HD. However as was concluded in this thread about [The Sage Familiar Archetype & Sage's Knowledge (Ex)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106831/about-familiar-archetype-sage-and-sages-knowledge/106836#106836), a sage familiar would have to base its skills off of the base creature's which if you do the math used a sp/HD.

> Sage’s Knowledge (Ex) 
>   - A sage stores information on every topic and is happy to lecture its master on the finer points. A sage can attempt all Knowledge checks untrained and receives a bonus on all Knowledge checks equal to 1/2 its level. Additionally, a sage gains 2 skill ranks at each level.

So,

1. does a sage familiar get 2 or 3 sp/(hd or wizard level)
2. does a regular old familiar actually get a sp/level, like a druids animal companion?

I kind of think its actually 2 to 1. and no to 2. With the sage archetype a familiar gives up a decent amount, alertness and the wizard's 8 skill point fed perception etc, to be able to put skill points in whatever it wants. Oh say.. Use Magic Device for instance. However if my planned Nosoi familiar can pop a point into UMD and use my score for the skill.... well, whoo hoo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pseudodragon familiar and Skill Points](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131195/pseudodragon-familiar-and-skill-points)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the last comment in the following thread answers my question pretty well:

- [Paizo Forums Answer](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2thu8?Sage-Familiar-archetype-and-skill-points#2).

Familiars get the base creatures skills and racial modifiers and IntBonus/HD skill points. Normal familiars never get more than 1HD, but Improved Familiars get more. Sages add 2/character level to that, but give up alot. Its a useful archetype for classes without skills to spare on knowledge.